# VS CODE terminal is not opening showing error The terminal process failed to launch

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code

I have a brand new laptop and install vs code in it but when I try to open the terminal in vs code it shows the following error as a notification like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAkTK.png).

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" does not exist.
```

I had tried to change some settings.json in vs code, but nothing works for me. please help me to start terminal in vs code.

Comment: Did you check the path in the error message? Did you find `powershell.exe` there?

Comment: Also try installing [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/latest).

Comment: run this >>> `(Get-Command pwsh.exe).Source` <<< and you should see where your ps7 install is located.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey the configuration shown in the screen is for powershell 5.1 on windows, the environment is OSx. It is needed either to install powershell core or configure vscode to use an existing pwsh.

Comment: @MikeL'Angelo - my intent is to find out where the ps7 install is currently located. that does not need VSCode ... only the console for pwsh.exe - and i presume that can be loaded from any macos console. i cannot test that, tho.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, macos does not have powershell core installed by default. powershell core in macos is called pwsh (as opposed to pwsh.exe). The original question is how to start a terminal in vscode using any version of powershell. For this to happen one has to identify the os, install the powershell core, configure vscode to open a terminal using it. - but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @MikeL'Angelo - arg! i completely misread the "installed" sentence in the Question. it only refers to VSCode, not to both VSCode and PwSh. [*blush*] thank you for getting me to finally see that ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows your environment is OSx. [Install Powershell Core for OSx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7.1) and [configure VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) to use it.